# Average pending time too high Firebase Real time Database

Tags: mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was profiling the Realtime Database and found it to be too slow.
[image]

The average pending time is almost 700 ms(sometimes even 1.5-2s). It was taking almost 7-12 seconds to perform 2000 write operations which is too slow. And I was wondering whether I should switch to mongodb or some other db instead as I am going to require fast performance and that is a priority.

Or in the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile#:%7E:text=Average%20Pending%20Time%3A%20The%20average,pending%20time%20and%20execution%20speed.) it is given that I should try sharding the database.

Is mongodb going to give me better performance? Is it worth switching, given that I am using firebase auth and also some other features?

The aim is to have up to 300-500k writes per second. With the limit of 1000 writes per second per database in firebase, sharding across 300-500 databases doesn't seem to be a good idea.

What can be the solution to have a faster database.

Second of all I am not even reaching 1000 writes/second. 10 sec for 2000 writes is a fifth of the limit. What can be done

I am processing the orders and removing the order from pendingOrders and writing it in completedOrders. Both are root level collections.

Is there something wrong with the way I am calling the write operation or with the way I have structured the data.
pendingOrders and completedOrders are both root level collections having orders.

```
orders = db.NewRef("/")

if err := orders.Update(ctx, map[string]interface{}{
    "completedOrders/" + id: &ob.OrderJSON{
        ID:        id,
        S:         side,
        Timestamp: timestamp,
        Quantity:  quantity,
        Price:     price,
    },
    "pendingOrders/" + id: nil,
}); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error pushing child node:", err)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if mongo has "better write times" but have you tried to write with a batch? Maybe could also try Firebase Firestore.

Comment: firestore charges per read/write so will be more expensive.
Can you explain how to batch write in realtime database?

Comment: The equivalent to a batch write in RTDB would be a multi-location update: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html

Comment: The problem with batch writing is if just one write fails all the writes in the batch will fail.
Also can you give an example as to how to write multiple orders? I have edited the question as to how i am writing  it now.

Comment: *It was taking almost 7-12 seconds to perform 2000 write operations which is too slow* - that's not at all what we experience. We write 2000 operations in about 2.5 seconds which is "as advertised" (I just coded up an app that does that). Our environment is macOS/Swift. I am guessing that the testing is affected by some other influence - hard to say with so many variables involved.

Comment: I dont think the env is the problem macOS(m1)/ Golang. I will look more into what I might be doing wrong. Thanks for the response.